# Recursive Decaying Average in Sql Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, recursion, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I need to calculate a decaying average (cumulative moving?) of a set of values. The last value in the series is 50% weight, with the decayed average of all the prior series as the other 50% weight, recursively.

I came up with a CTE query that produces correct results, but it depends on a sequential row number. I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this in SQL 2012, maybe with the new windowing functions for Over(), or something like that?

In the live data, the rows are ordered by time. I can use an SQL view and ROW_NUMBER() to generate the necessary Row field for my CTE approach, but if there is a more efficient way to do this, I would like to keep this as efficient as possible.

I have a sample table with 2 columns: Row int, and Value Float. I have 6 sample data values of 1,2,3,4,4,4. The correct result should be 3.78125.

My solution is:

```
;WITH items AS (
  SELECT TOP 1 
    Row, Value, Value AS Decayed
    FROM Sample Order By Row
  UNION ALL
  SELECT v.Row, v.Value, Decayed * .5 + v.Value *.5 AS Decayed
  FROM Sample v
  INNER JOIN items itms ON itms.Row = v.Row-1
  )
SELECT top 1 Decayed FROM items order by Row desc
```

This correctly produces 3.78125 with the test data. My question is: Is there a more efficient and/or simpler way to do this in SQL 2012, or is this about the only way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Is your recursive CTE result definitely correct? In that the first row decays less relatively to all other rows? If not remove the `iif` from my answer.

Comment: It is correct. But the first row isn't really special. The result for 1 element is just the value of that element. Add a second element, the prior result count 50% weight, and the new value counts 50%. Add third value, then prior result (of first 2 elements) is 50%, and 3rd element is 50%. And so on until end of series. The last element is always 50% weight, and the other 50% is the prior result before that last element added.

Comment: Well it's special in that when you look at the amount it ends up contributing to the final total it's the only row not half as much again as its successor. Because it doesn't get halved until the second row comes into play and the second row is halved immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible alternative would be

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT      
 Value * POWER(5E-1, ROW_NUMBER() 
                     OVER (ORDER BY Row DESC)
               /* first row decays less so special cased */
              -IIF(LEAD(Value) OVER (ORDER BY Row DESC) IS NULL,1,0))
       as x
FROM Sample
)
SELECT SUM(x)
FROM T
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7e849/1)

Or for the updated question using 60%/40%

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT   IIF(LEAD(Value) OVER (ORDER BY Row DESC) IS NULL,  1,0.6)
         * Value 
         * POWER(4E-1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Row DESC) -1)
       as x
FROM Sample
)
SELECT SUM(x)
FROM T
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c6dd2/1)

both of the above perform a single pass through the data and can potentially use an index on `Row INCLUDE(Value)` to avoid a sort.

Comment: It looks like that does give the same result for the sample series, and with a few other sample series it matches mine too. And it sure looks like it would be a lot more efficient. Only problem is I have no idea how or why it works :) Guess I've got some reading to do. What if the weights were different? Say if the last element was weighted 60%, and the prior result was 40%. Would this approach still work?

Comment: Yup, looks like that latest version of the fiddle above does everything correctly, even with different weightings. Have to say I never would have come up with that on my own, so I'm glad I asked on here. If Management Studio's "Query Cost" estimates are accurate, your solution is twice as fast as mine too. Thanks for the help.